# USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size

Tags: usb-flash-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure, community-faq

I have a USB flash drive which is no longer recognized by my computer. Windows Disk Management and DiskPart report **No Media** with no storage space (0 bytes) on the drive and I cannot partition or format the drive:

[image: Console window with DiskPart showing "No Media" on the flash drive]

*[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/311111/how-do-i-fix-a-memorex-usb-8gb-flash-drive-that-shows-0-b-available)*

If the drive appears in Windows Explorer, trying to access it returns an error message indicating that there is no disk inserted, such as the following:

> Please insert a disk into drive X:.

Various disk partitioning and data recovery utilities don't recognize the drive or only give a generic name for the drive and cannot access the contents of the drive.

What can I do? How do I recover data from the drive?

> *This question comes up often and the answers are usually the same. This post is meant to provide a definitive, canonical answer for this problem. Feel free to edit the answer to add additional details.*

Comment: List of duplicates: http://superuser.com/q/538383, http://superuser.com/q/871762, http://superuser.com/q/431073, http://superuser.com/q/311111, http://superuser.com/q/819820, http://superuser.com/q/692929, http://superuser.com/q/746344, http://superuser.com/q/373508, http://superuser.com/q/200910, http://superuser.com/q/73754, http://superuser.com/q/101190, http://superuser.com/q/327707, http://superuser.com/q/426218, http://superuser.com/q/445728, http://superuser.com/q/839177

Comment: For housekeeping: see also the question "[What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/q/1125282)".

Comment: Related:  [How do I fix my USB drive  to get its original size back?](https://superuser.com/q/382242/354511)

Comment: @bwDraco I didn't click on all of those, but this question specifically addresses the "no media" question. That's why it's in bold.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Failing Flash Drive**

"No Media" means the flash memory controller cannot communicate with the NAND flash memory on the drive.  Because of this, it appears to the computer as an empty disk drive. This is usually caused by the NAND flash failing. To the computer, the drive is not much different than a floppy or optical drive with no disk inserted.

As a result, it is not possible to access any data on the drive, nor is it possible to repartition or reformat the drive. Again, from the standpoint of the computer, there is no medium in the drive to be formatted or repartitioned.

**Fake Drive?**

It is also possible that the drive is fake and the cheap memory chip in the drive has failed. Drives failing in this manner will often show up as a storage device with 8MB capacity.

**Potential Hardware-Specific Restoration**

*From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/693176/73918):* You can obtain more information about the drive and its controller using a tool called [ChipGenius](http://www.usbdev.ru/files/chipgenius/). You might be able to recover the drive hardware by using a tool such as [Bootice](http://agnipulse.com/2010/10/easily-modify-bootsector-bootice/) to manipulate the MBR.

Additionally, if the drive uses a Phison controller, you may be able to use the [Phison USB Mass Production Tools](http://flashboot.ru/files/phison/) to reprogram the controller and restore normal operation.  Note that doing this will erase all data on the drive.

**Data Recovery**

In cases where stored information is merely corrupted, consumer data recovery software can often recover the contents.  However, that won't work if the drive fails as described here.

There are data recovery services that can use special equipment to try to recover content from the chips.  However, it is expensive.  If you can't restore the drive to normal operation, it probably isn't worth sending it to a data recovery service unless the data stored on the drive is particularly valuable.  You should simply replace the drive.

Comment: Jake Gould: I'm not sure if I agree with your edit. I won't be around much longer today, but the answer is deliberately structured in this fashion. To understand why I format my answers this way, see [recent answers posted by Thaddeus](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2765/thaddeus?tab=answers) at [scifi.se]. Let me know what you think about this format, perhaps in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19572/feedback-for-dragonlords-new-post-style), and I will respond tomorrow.

Comment: @JakeGould ultimately you should respect the wishes of the person who originally wrote a post if there's disagreement about an edit (unless we're talking something completely inappropriate). I agree though that heading formatting shouldn't be abused to make text stand out (it should be used for headings in long posts), and I think your edits were appropriate.

Comment: Restored the header, but with shorter text, per http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9106/is-it-okay-to-use-headers-to-summarize-content/9107#9107.

Comment: @DragonLord - This has already been edited a lot, but I wanted to see what you thought of a slightly different approach to structuring it. What was previously highlighted was the logic that ties everything together, but that isn't the most critical part of the answer. I took a shot at structuring it more focused around the solution (what people will be looking for).  Feel free to roll it back or play with it.  Just a rough serving suggestion.

Comment: @fixer1234: Thanks for the edit – I'll keep it and may build on it in the future.

Comment: I have had lots of luck with the [HP USB Recovery Tool](http://download.cnet.com/HP-USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool/3000-2094_4-10974082.html).

Comment: That ChipGenius link is broken - maybe you could fix it. There's a [Russian site](http://www.usbdev.ru/files/chipgenius/) which appears to be it's official site, but maybe you had a different one in mind ?

Comment: @fixer1234, message from the future: love your edit! Those lite headings matter _so much_! We may not know until we are tired and sleepless, running constantly overloaded etc. (bwDraco, great answer, too!)

Comment: The executable files from the ChipGenius web site linked above conains trojans according to 38/71 engines on VirusTotal: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/d42736052810166f929b11e986a7e20a2fb3e2d686473fb07a8aa2b7e9421d38/detection

Comment: If goal is data recovery, all these in situ fix suggestions are a bad idea. A nice alternative to ChipGenius is https://www.antspec.com/usbflashinfo/index.php

Comment: All the BOOTICE download links now fail. So, there's no longer a solution here.

Answer (score 5):

Go to MyComputer/Manage/USB Controller/USB Mass Storage/Unistall while plugged, then remove it, and re-plug in, the driver will -re-installed. It solved it on my computer.

Comment: 1: I knew my USB Drive was fine, but had been used as a bootable USB to install Windows. This suggestion made it possible for me to see the entire partition in Disk Management.

2: I had no data I needed to recover on it, so I cleaned it before the last step; this can maybe be avoided if you have... I went to `diskpart` (open in CMD): 

2.1: `list disk`

2.2: `sel disk x`

2.3: `clean` 

3: Finally, to be able to format it again, I wen into the drives properties and under _policies_ and switched it to _"Optimize for performance"_ (instead of _"Optimize for quick removal"_).

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: before you do, just try the USB flash drive in different PC to determine if issue is local PC issue or not.

Answer (score 3):

This may happen also when there is insufficient power supply to the flash from the usb port.  Check that you are not overloading the usb ports with power hungry peripheralas.  Also tortured USB cables, if there are any connected, may sometimes leak current and reduce the available power.

Answer (score 2):

The flash drive is fried, or at least not functioning. I did this to save the content: put it in the freezer for a couple of hours, and it appeared again for just enough time to copy the contents to the harddrive. Then it disappeared again.

Comment: Actually? Or is it a pun.

Comment: @KovyJacob FWIW sometimes cold or heat can change how NAND behaves. I do not have a scientific explanation, but data recovery labs use this 'wisdom' all the time. Although they try do this in a more controller fashion. It's not something that will just always work, which is what I have such generic advices "just put it in freezer".