# Flash drive not recognized

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, hard-drive-recovery, disk-management

I was copying some files to my flash drive and removed it from my laptop.  When I plugged it into my PC, it didn't recognize it and it doesn't show up in disk management, and I can't find it in device manager. It's the same on my PC and my laptop.  The only thing I can find online is assigning a drive letter from disk management, but like I said,  it's not there. Anyone know how I can fix it?  The files are backed up but I need my flash drive

Comment: possible duplicate of [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](http://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem)

Comment: It’s possible that there might be an hardware issue with your computer’s USB port, a driver problem with your Windows computer, or you may just have a dead drive.
First, unplug the drive from your USB port and try plugging it into another USB port on your computer. If it works in one USB port but not another, you may have a dead USB port.

Comment: @DavidPostill no,  this isn't a duplicate. That post is about a flash drive that shows up as no media,  mine just isn't there.

Comment: @vembutech Like i said, it happens on two separate computers, so its not port or driver issues. What i cant explain to myself is how a drive could die when i just ejected it from my laptop, walked to my desktop, and boom, it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is not a common situation probably but here's what was happening. I had used that flash drive on a homebrew Wii a few days ago, and hadn't used it again. Apparently it hadn't been ejected properly on the Wii, and Windows read it but broke it trying to close it. Putting it back in the Wii and removing it properly fixed it. I figured this out when it happened with another drive again, I guess it's some bug in the Wii's USB deiver.