# Device not initialized, can't reformat

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, formatting, disk-management

So I'm unable to access my flash drive because it doesn't initialize when I plug it into my computer, and when I try to initialize it I get "device not ready." There's nothing incredibly important on it so I thought I'd just reformat it, but I don't seem to be able to do that either since there seems to be no drive space for me to format. (the area in pic attached that is all grey and next to "disk 2" is what I'm trying to reformat, but it won't let me do anything) Is there anything I can do other than just throwing it out?

[image]

Comment: What menu do you get if you right click in device manager where is says Disk2 unknown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](http://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem)

Answer (score 0):

**This will wipe the drive. All your data on it will be lost**

- Open command prompt as admin (Win + X then A)
- type "diskpart"
- type "list disk"
- type "select disk x" (*where x is the number for your USB drive. Match it based on storage space, and make sure you get it right*)
- type "clean"
- type "create partition primary"
- type "format fs=fat32 label=NAME quick" (*change NAME to what you want to call the USB*)