# Size 0 B listed in diskpart, can't create partition

Tags: windows, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, diskpart

I have a 4GB flash drive that I'm trying to use, but it seems to have become corrupted somehow. When I run list disk, it shows Size 0B Free 0B, and tryig to create a primary partition gives "DiskPart has encountered an error: The Device is not Ready." I'm not really sure what more I can do. It was working perfectly this morning but when I plugged it into my PC this afternoon I get this. I've tried this with W7 and W10

Comment: Dupe: [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](http://superuser.com/q/871850)

Comment: The difference between my problem and theirs is that my diskpart lists its status as "online", not "no media"

Also, all of the bootice links on that response give 404 and 503 errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem)