# Did I destroy my USB stick? (Invisible when plugging in, lsusb works.)

Tags: usb-flash-drive, fdisk, lsusb

I tried to create a multiboot USB following this tutorial:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/#more-5352

But Instead of getting a bootable USB I am not able to detect it in my Kubuntu 16.10 nor Windows 10.

If I plug it in the computer, Kubuntu does not say anything, Windows 10 says, that the device is probably broken.

I tried to list it with `fdisk -l` as sudo:

```
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             2048    1026047    1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          1026048  308226047  307200000 146.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        308228094 1953523711 1645295618 784.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5        308228096  356663642   48435547  23.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6        357056512 1943758847 1586702336 756.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       1943760896 1953523711    9762816   4.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8  *     356665344  357054463     389120   190M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

None of these is my USB stick. When I plug it in, nothing changes.

But when I run lsusb as root, when I plug the USB in, i get a new line in the list:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:1234 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
```

Is there a way to make the USB stick visible again? On some forums I found ifnormation, that this behavior mostly means, that the USB stick is physically broken. But I don't think so since It happened after running some fdisk operations on it.

(Sorry about my English.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](http://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem)

Comment: It isn't clear that this is a duplicate since lsusb recognizes it.

Comment: I've found quite a bunch of similar questions, but none of them I've found was exactly the same (and none of them offered a working solution for my case).