# USB pen drive not recognized after using UNetbootin. Why?

Tags: windows-7, linux, bootable-media, backtrack, unetbootin

I am running Windows-7 32-bit on my computer. I came across an article glorifying Backtrack Linux and so I wanted to try it.

I downloaded the Backtrack5 RC3 (Live CD) ISO from softpedia and UNetbootin from Unetbootin's github webpage...and I "burned" the ISO image to my USB pen drive ([Kingston DataTraveler G2 (4GB variant)](https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/DTIG2_us.pdf)) using UNetbootin.

Then I removed my USB "safely" using Windows7's "Safely Remove your USB device" wizard.

The problems started thereafter...thereafter, my USB isn't being recognized by Windows...neither my own, nor that of a friend's laptop...I'm shown the "USB Device Not Recognized Popup"!!

Also, even though I've given higher preference to USB devices in my BIOS' boot order (I'v pushed HDD down to the last preference), my computer won't boot from the bootable USB.

- Here, I would like to clarify that I am able to boot from my Windows7 Recovery USB...meaning my BIOS does support USB booting.

UNetbootin suggests that I re-write the USB with the distribution, but I can't do so because Windows doesn't show the USB in "My Computer" section or in the "Device Management" section anymore...meaning I can't re-format the pen drive (a pre-requisite to re-write the distribution).

**So I have the following questions:**

*1. How can I regain control of my Pen Drive?*

*2. Also,  I've been reading a lot about MBR issue with such Pen Drives...could it be same in my case? How can I restore the MBR to reclaim my pen drive..when it's not being recognized by windows7?*

---

---

Since having posted my question, I worked on the suggestions offered and the results have been like this:

1. When I run "Diskpart->list disk", I only get "disk 0" corresponding to my HDD..."list disk" doesn't list my USB pen drive.
2. Also, in "My Computer->Device Manager", I cannot see my USB under the Disk Drive etc...all it does is to list it as an "Unknown Device" under "Universal Serial Bus Controllers".
3. When I run USBView.exe, all it does is to show "[Port4] FailedEnumeration : Unknown Device" when I plug in my Pen Drive. The detailed report is as follows:

> ```
>    [Port4] FailedEnumeration :  Unknown Device
> ```

```
   ---===>Device Information<===---

   ConnectionStatus:                  FailedEnumeration
   Current Config Value:              0x00  -> Device Bus Speed: Low
   Device Address:                    0x00
   Open Pipes:                           0
   *!*ERROR:  No open pipes!

             ===>Device Descriptor<===
   *!*ERROR:  bLength of 0 incorrect, should be 18
   bLength:                           0x00
   bDescriptorType:                   0x00
   bcdUSB:                          0x0000
   bDeviceClass:                      0x00
   *!*ERROR:  Device enumeration failure
```

---

Images of my pen drive (for IC Bridge identification):

[image: Front side of the pen drive (Don't know why this is being shown in Portrait view when the pic I uploaded was in Landscape view!)]
[image: Back side of the pen drive]
In this 2nd photograph, the text written (in dark-brown text) above the white label is 'Toshiba E5 104'. Could this be the IC bridge type?

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem

Comment: Does it show in USBview.exe in any shape or form?

Comment: just an Idea : right click my comp -> manage -> disk management -> find your USB drive. Its highly possible that your USB might not show its name rather some `drive - f` or something like that. After that right click on it and format...proceed as instructed and try to set everything to default. Tell me if this works.

Comment: @fixer1234: It's not a duplicate of the thread you mentioned. Here's why...why I run "Diskpart list disk", I only get "disk 0" corresponding to my HDD..."list disk" doesn't list my USB pen drive. Also, in "My Computer->Device Manager", I cannot see my USB under the Disk Drive etc...all it does is to list it as an "Unknown Device" under "Universal Serial Bus Controllers".

Comment: @AliChen: All that USBView.exe does is to show "[Port4] FailedEnumeration :  Unknown Device" when I plug in my Pen Drive..

Comment: @MukulKumar: Disk Management doesn't list my pen drive in any form...It lists only these three items: Disc0 (for my HDD), CD-ROM0 (for my DVD-Drive), CD-ROM1 (for Daemon Tools' virtual drive).

Comment: @ComputerUser, what brand is your pen drive? SanDisk?

Comment: @ComputerUser, does the USBview report any meaningful descriptor info? Does it determine the speed of connection properly as HS? It looks like you have run into a typical misfortune on some brands of pen drives, where some write activity (typically from Linux environment) screws up basic USB functionality by corrupting something.

Comment: @AliChen: Mine is Kingston DataTraveler G2 (4GB variant...the yellow one). Regarding speed, the "Device Information" section has a "Device Device Bus Speed:" showing "Low". This is interesting because when I plug in the dongle of my Logitech wireless mouse in that very port, it reports "Device Bus Speed: Full"!!

Comment: @AliChen: I've been reading a lot about MBR issue with such Pen Drives...could it be same in my case? How can I restore the MBR to reclaim my pen drive..when it's not being recognized by windows7?

Comment: @ComputerUser,   If USBview says "Low" and doesn't show any descriptors, it means the USB connect protocol is totally destroyed at hardware level, the pen is completely out, since "low" means total nonsense. If it doesn't connect as HS/FS Mass storage device, no MBR medicine can help, since it is on higher logical level. I am afraid your pen is lost. Best you can do for humanitarian reasons is to open it up and report the type of IC bridge inside it.

Comment: @AliChen: Umm...Can I report back the IC bridge on 10th December? (My exams have come on my head! ..Sorry for this break in the conversation..)

Comment: @AliChen: I'm so sorry I coiuldn't understand the type of IC bridge by looking at the pen drive. I've uploaded photographs of the pen drive...can you make out the type of IC bridge from them?

Comment: The bridge is SSS6690  by "Solid State Systems". The second is Toshiba flash memory IC. To repair, try this link http://www.flashdrive-repair.com/2014/05/sss6686-usb-mass-production-utility.html Although, if it doesn't connect as USB device, chances for repair at host system are dim. As I can see from the Web, people have troubles with this bridge.

Comment: @AliChen You were right! The repair tool didn't help! :D

Comment: @AliChen: Out of curiosity, how did you figure out the details? I understand the Toshiba bit. But I couldn't locate the IC written anywhere on the pen drive..so how did you figure that out? Is there a guide somewhere?

Comment: @ComputerUser, I don't remember. I believe I googled for all numbers as they appear on IC inscription.