# MicroSD card: can't format,or partition

Tags: partitioning, formatting, sd-card, micro-sd-card, dban

TL;DR: I have a Micro-SD card that has a primary partition that isn't formatted and can't be selected and I have tried:

- DBAN nuke (wiped)
- Windows formatting
- 3rd party program formatting
- diskpart.exe
- Windows partition manager

I can't get it to work, please help.

I bought a micro-SD card which I had Kali Linux on and later wiped it as I wanted to use the card in my phone instead. The card failed and I think I messed up with the format of the card or my phone is too bad to work properly with an SD (cheap Chinese android). I am trying to re use it again to put Kali back on it but I am having problems.

When I try to connect it, it detects and no damage that I can recall reader is working too, Windows says I need to format it before I can use it. It just tries to and says Windows could not do it. I tried to check if there was maybe an issue with the partitions in it so I tried to select it in diskpart.exe and it recognizes the card but when I try to select the "primary" part, it just spits out: "There is no partition selected". The primary partition is active and I can't delete it because it won't select it and I can't create a new partition because the primary partition is there is taking the full size of the SD card but can't be selected.

I have also tried a DBAN nuke to clear any and all data off, it and, it just plain won't work. Formatting, partitioning and wiping it have all failed and it has no clear damage on it (bought this year). Anyone have something else I could try?

Comment: Try the SD Card in another computer.  Try a different, known-good SD card in your computer.  If the card in question fails, and the known-good  one works, then you know it's the SD card that's bad.

Comment: I don't think I have another MircoSD card but I get the same result on other computers and the card reader is also not the problem. I might buy another one to both test if the card is the problem but I would prefer to try and fix it first.

Comment: You've tried, it's dead, buy a new one. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem)

Comment: It is often the case when the device is broken. Most of manufacturer introduced a protection to switch to Read Only the all card if one faulty sector was detected... Poor

Answer (score 6):

Many cards and USB sticks go into "read only" mode when the controller decides the memory is malfunctioning. Had this happen to SanDisk USB sticks when you wear them out (used as continuous backup). No idea how the device decides when it can't take any more. Only the manufacturer can answer that.

Comment: After every other hypothesis, this is the proper response. Few know there is this manufacturer protection.

Comment: I confirm this looks solid, and I think that's what's happening to my card as well. I tried over 10 methods for wiping data on my SD Card and it just refused to write or delete any of it whatsoever. Similar: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/65241/what-happens-when-read-or-write-failures-occur-on-sd-card

Answer (score 4):

I have had some luck recovering cards using the SD Card Formatter utility from SD Association.

https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/

Once formatted back to the SD standard you may be able to then do something else.

Comment: It said 'write protection enabled'. Anyone know how to change this?

Comment: If you are using a micro-SD to SD adapter the adapter may have a write-protection or lock switch.  Make sure the switch is in the unlocked position.

Comment: @MattyG Certainly the manufacturer protection when something went wrong with some sectors. Nothing to do but replace the card. Micro SD are very verty sensitive... it's often a bad choice when you know you will touch it a lot.