# USB Stick is recognized by PC but cannot be opened

Tags: usb, drivers, usb-flash-drive

My new USB Stick with important data can't be opened by my or my friend's Windows Computer anymore. I can tell that it is recognized by it since a "device" is "mounted" under E:/ and my computer makes a sound when I connect it but it won't show the USB's original name nor does it allow me to access the data.

When I click on it it asks me to insert a USB-Drive.

1. I have tried already to deactivate and reactivate the USB Stick
2. to deinstall and reinstall drivers for the USB-Stick
3. to rename the driver letter from E:/ to P:/ and back to E:/
4. and put it into the freezer for 20 minutes (my friend recommended this)

I hope anybody can help me out with this as the data is really important to me.

Here is the data that my system gives me for the Stick:

- Device Name = Port_#0003.Hub_#0001
- Description = Samsung Flash Drive FIT USB Device
- Device Type = Mass Storage
- Connected  = Yes
- Safe To Unplug  = Yes
- Disabled  = No
- USB Hub = No
- Drive Letter = E:
- Serial Number = 0329516090014309
- Created Date = 25.12.2016 18:22:06
- Last Plug/Unplug Date = 25.12.2016 16:54:20
- VendorID = 090c
- ProductID = 1000
- Firmware Revision = 11.00
- USB SubClass = 06
- USB Protocol = 50
- USB Class = 08
- Service Name = USBSTOR
- Service Description = @usbstor.inf,%USBSTOR.SvcDesc%;USB Mass Storage Driver
- Driver Filename = USBSTOR.SYS
- Device Mfg = Compatible USB storage device
- USB Version = 2.10
- Driver Description = USB Mass Storage Device
- Driver Version = 10.0.14393.0
- Driver InfSection = USBSTOR_BULK.NT
- Driver InfPath = usbstor.inf
- Instance ID = USB\VID_090C&PID_1000\0329516090014309
- Capabilities = Removable, UniqueID, SurpriseRemovalOK

Edit 25.12.2016 - Opposed to another question posted here I have no access to the storage size information of my flash drive - hence it must be a different problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](http://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem)

Comment: Did you try : chkdsk E: /f /r  ?

Comment: @Wiffzack I just tried it and it tells me: Volume can not be opened for direct access.

Comment: What file system is on the USB drive? If it's ext*n* as used by Linux, you might want to try a tool such as DiskInternals Linux Reader.

Comment: Did you run cmd as an administrator?Force Undeployment: chkdsk E: /f /r /x

Comment: Filesystem is FAT - It has worked on this Computer (Windows 10) just a couple hours ago.

Comment: Did you try formatting it in storage management console?

Comment: @xR34P3Rx no I have not - I need the data that is on it :(

Comment: @DenDen what i would do is get yourself a linux live CD and in the live session see if linux can read the USB, if it can, copy your files from the USB to your HD temporarily. Once thats done, use `gparted` in the live session to reformat the USB drive. if the live session doesnt have `gparted` just run `sudo apt-get install gparted` assuming its ubuntu/debian. Then go back into windows and see if the USB can be read again.

Comment: @xR34P3Rx Linux wont mount the USB drive as well - tried it manually

Comment: @DenDen are you doing it from the terminal? are you using `fdisk -l`?

Answer (score 0):

If even chkdsk cannot access the stick, it is possible that the stick is formatted in a file system that Windows does not recognize - possibly ext{2,4}. You can do one of these:

This tutorial (http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/) cites three tools/drivers to access to extX from Windows directly:

- Ext2Fsd (http://www.ext2fsd.com/)
- Diskinternals (https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/)
- Ext2Read (https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/)

Apart from that, there are two ways that you can easily deploy Linux without interrupting your Windows installation:

- You can install Virtualbox and add a lightweight and easily installed Linux distribution (such as Lubuntu, or Puppy Linux) as a VM.
- You can install a lightweight and easily installed Linux distribution (such as Lubuntu, or maybe Puppy Linux) to a USB (provided that you have at least two USB ports, or a USB hub).

In USB installation, you can easily copy the contents of the disk to the Windows partition. In the case of Virtualbox VM, you have to define a shared folder, so that Linux and Windows can share files.

Comment: thanks for your reply - but the USB Stick has worked on my computer before and I have tried connecting it to a linux PC already.

Comment: Is it ever mounted on Linux? What did happen? Can you provide some more information. If the case is that the disk is corrupted, I will recommend a tool to extract the filesystem in it.

Comment: I tried mounting on Ubuntu VirtualBox but it won't mount nor show up in dmseg | tail etc.

Comment: Kernel For Windows Data Recovery (https://www.kerneldatarecovery.com/windows-data-recovery.html). FAT and NTFS file systems may get corrupt esaily when data writing process is interrupted. This utility will find and report the files first and then charge you if you want to recover them. I used that for a 500 GB HDD and recovered a large portion of important data.

Comment: By the way, if it does show up in `ls -t /dev | grep sd`, you can try it mount it manually?

Comment: You can also try dosfsck to check FAT drive from Linux as per this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/147228/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-fat32-file-system

Comment: ls -t /dev | grep sd gives me a couple sda which I believe sda2 is my usb flash drive. When trying to mount it mannually I get the response "bad superblock"

Comment: Unplug, run that again, an repeat after plugging, be sure so that you don't deal with a wrong drive.

Comment: Possibly it is corrupted. Try dosfsck from Linux, and if no use, try Kernel For Windows. It will cost some (but after you see it works) but your data may be more valuable.

Comment: Cevikal you are right I disconnected the flash drive and sda2 remains - it is not sda2 - so linux doesn't recognize either.

Comment: I think we are nearly sure that the drive is corrupted. Did you run dosfsck?