# Recovering a pen drive

Tags: usb, memory, usb-flash-drive, data-recovery

I have a 32GB pendrive that ive had for quite a while and that always worked without problems but today I just plugged it in to realize that the pen drive had lost his name(was just showing "F:" without any name-- it had a name before) and also that when I opened it, it was showing like if it was empty.However if I right click on it, it clearly show that my files are there(only 110mb free space).I looked up a bit online and tried the command line method:

with the Windows CMD in my pendrive( f: ) I did

```
attrib *.* -r -h -s /d /s
```

wich created a FOUND.000 folder of a size of 29GB on the pen drive with 9633 .CHK file in it... I then found a little program (called unCHK) wich as I understood "rebuild" the CHK files together to result as the actual file. I started the process wich was taking forever, it failed because after 1% done, the folder that was outputting the "rebuilt" files in it was already of a size of 120GB??? So my hard drive was full..So this utility is, I guess, almost impossible to use unless you have a crazy size hard drive to output your files on... plus getting to 1% took almost an hour + so getting to 100% would take like 4 days non stop..So now I am wondering if somebody would have a solution to recover these files, I have no idea what happened I did nothing wrong with that pen drive I have no idea of what happened.

thank you

EDIT: Ive found another software(freeware) called Chk-Back--dont want to do any advertisment--wich was way faster and seemed more up to date than unCHK. I was able to recover a good part of my files(not 100% of them--some where in "uncommon" format, well format that the Chk-back software didnt know, so these were not recovered)

Comment: Most likely the drive has failed, not unusual for such devices. Be aware that flash drives are among the least reliable of modern storage media and should not be used for primary storage of important files. Add to that the possibility they may be lost, stolen, or physically damaged. They should be used primarily as a transport media. All files of any importance need at least one backup copy, 2 or more backup copies if the files are of particular importance. Sorry, can't help with recovery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem)

Comment: @LMiller7 thank you still, see my edited post, Ive recovered good part of my files, even tho I lost the files names and folder(all the files are now named FILE0001-FILE9596)but at least I got them back.Still dont understand what happened, since it looks like the files themselves were not corrupted but they were just not showing up, I guess like you said its more a hardware/pendrive problem--Ive formatted the pendrive using normal(not quick) format, could that have "fixed" the pendrive? thanks