# USB Drive "No Media" error

Tags: usb-flash-drive, freenas

This USB drive used to be "FreeNAS" boot drive, when I have it plugged into my Windows 10 machine, it shows as a "removable device" but can not access it.

I was trying to use "Diskpart", it shows as a disk and can be selected. but if I try to "Clean" it, it shows me "Virtual Disk Service error: There is no media in the device."

I tried to use Linux and other utilities to format it, but they dont even recognize this USB drive.

What did FreeNAS do to it and How can I format this USB drive again?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem)