# Can't format my 16 gb USB Drive

Tags: hard-drive, usb, usb-flash-drive

I've tried to put a mac os dmg file with win32diskimager and it gave me an error, I can't remember the error but since then the USB drive it shows me: There is no media in the device (0 bytes). I've tried format it with diskpart but it shows me also no media. I've tried format it with gparted in Linux it gave me input/output error, also with Disk Utility can't format it.Test disk doesn't recognizes the USB drive.Through the terminal I've tried these commands:

`fdisk -l` doesn't show up

```
lsblk:NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   20G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0   20G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1 14,4G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1 14,4G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1   55M  0 rom  /media/marius/Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon 64-bit
```

Sdb1 is the USB drive.
What should I do?

Comment: Buy a new thumb drive.

Comment: Is sdb the thumb drive?

Comment: The Usb drive is sdb1 and it's 14,4G,also in windows when i plug it in it shows me something like this:https://imgur.com/a/MNal3mE and when i double click it,it's empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem)

Comment: input/output error may also caused by incompatibility of realtek card reader/linux kernel https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/511194

Comment: I think that the USB Drive is broken.It is a SSS 6131 controller and maybe in the future i will manage to write it's firmware with a tool