# USB drive ejects itself while formatting

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I have a 32GB Toshiba USB drive. Recently I tried writing an image of chrome OS to it with [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/). It failed. Since then my drive has been unreadable on both windows 10 and Ubuntu.

I have tried formatting it with disk management, diskpart, chrome OS recovery utility, easeus on windows and on Ubuntu I have tried Gparted, mkusb and fdisk. All of them could'nt complete the format. What I realized is that my USB drive always ejects in the middle of the formatting. Every single time so the process always doesn't complete.

Any ideas on why its doing that and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem

Comment: It may be a dead flashdrive or a corrupt/damaged block. Try mounting it manually in Linux. If that succeeds, try creating a filesystem on it. If mounting failed, look at dmesg for any clues. If it ejects while creating a filesystem, update the post with what you are busy with, the command line output (if avaialble) and the dmesg output.

Comment: Mounting in Linux: use `fdisk -l` to find the `/dev/sd(A,B,C,etc)` location. Then try mounting with `sudo mount /dev/sd(A,B,C,etc) /mnt/your/location`

Comment: seeing as it has no important data on it chuck it out and get a new one.