# USB Ejects itself when attempting to format or write to it

Tags: windows-10, usb

Similar to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1432980/usb-drive-ejects-itself-while-formatting) when I attempt to copy files to or format a USB stick it removes itself from my desktop. When I attempt to do this on my laptop, the issue does not occur. I can read from it fine.

I have tried running `diskpart` and got `attributes` but it shows all options as `No`, including read-only. I tried uninstalling my AV.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using "DISKPART" to clean and format the USB while it is connected to the laptop.

1.DISKPART > list disk
2.DISKPART > select (enter required usb disk number)
3.DISKPART > clean
4.DISKPART > create partition primary
5.DISKPART > active
6.DISKPART > select partition 1
7.DISKPART > format fs=fat32