# Fix USB stick that cannot be accessed, is not usable and is seen as portable device, not flash drive

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a USB stick that cannot be accessed and cannot be formatted, even if I use diskpart. When I try to open it an error pops up: "H:\ cannot be accessed. Incorrect function". This stick has 16GB, but Windows says that it has 0MB and has unusable memory. It has some data on it, but it's more important for me to make it functional. If you know also a method to recover my data let me know. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)