# Is it possible to repair this USB device or get the information out of it?

Tags: usb, data-recovery

This USB device had only one partition, but now it has two partitions and the second partition has an offset of 8MB, so I assume that there is a problem with the file system or partition table.

I have tried SystemRescueCd, gparted reads the usb as read-only.

Here's the picture attached:

[image: Picture]

tried testdisk here's what i got:

> Disk /dev/sdd - 134 GB / 125 GiB (RO) - Generic Flash Disk
>
> Write access for this media is not available.
> TestDisk won't be able to modify it.
>
> - This media may be physically write-protected, check the jumpers.

Comment: It doesn't have two partitions, it has one partition with some empty space before it. Flash drives corrupting themselves and/or becoming read-only is a sign that the drive has reached the end of its usable life or is otherwise damaged. How old is the drive? How heavily was it used? Is it within warranty? At best you might be able to recover data, but once this happens to a drive it should be treated as suspect and not trusted with any data you care about.

Comment: Possible duplicate [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only?noredirect=1&lq=1) and also [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports “No Media” with 0 bytes size](https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)

Comment: 2 things to try - 1. Get another drive, make a bitcopy of the data onto it (maybe using ddrescue) and then recover from that 2. Use photorec which will read the raw drive and dump fragments it recognises as media to another disk. (Photorec is a last-ditch tool as it can not retain filenames and does not handle fragmentation. It can be useful for recovering photos from a USB drive though).