# USB flash drive no longer recognised after copying files

Tags: hard-drive, usb, mount, rsync

I have an R+M USB 3.0 that is no longer recognised by my PC (running Windows 10). The disk appears greyed out, 0 bytes available, as in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem).

I don't mind about lost data, what I want to know is if I've done something wrong whilst backing up so I can prevent the same thing happening in the future. Here is the script I used to backup:

```
import subprocess           

drive = subprocess.run(['sudo', 'mount', '-t', 'drvfs', 'D:', '/mnt/d'])
print(drive)

docs = subprocess.run(['sudo', 'rsync', '-av', '--progress', '/mnt/c/Users/sc/Documents/', '/mnt/d', '--exclude', '/mnt/c/Users/sc/Documents/my_data/data'])
print(docs)

unmount = subprocess.run(['sudo', 'umount', '/mnt/d/'])
print(unmount)
```

I ran this and it caused my USB to break. Is this a bad method of backing up? Could this have been avoided if I'd zipped my files before copying? Or could it simply be that I bought a cheap, dodgy USB?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Its dead, replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not done anything wrong with respect of your backup method. Unless you very specifically seek out mechanisms to reprogrammed the firmware there is nothing you can do which will make a USB disk become 0 bytes unless it goes faulty.

Backing up with the commands you are using us fairly common.