# My Flash Drive isn't recognized anymore after I attempted cleaning via Command Prompt

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I tried to restore a flash drive of mine back to it's full capacity via the diskpart command. However when I wanted to clean the drive, it only resulted in me getting a Bluescreen and the Drive not being recognized afterwards. I have tried using it on a different Windows 10 machine to no avail.

Any ideas what happened there?

Comment: It's probably beyond repair now.

Comment: Yes, it's very probably dead. See http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only and https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem