# How to back alive an unusable USB key?

Tags: usb, partitioning, diskpart

I bought a usb key a few days ago and wanted to use it to install an OS with Rufus. During the copy of the data I had a power cut. After that, the USB key is no longer usable.

I tried the key an other PC and in an Ubuntu, it's the same.

The key is not visible in "This PC".

In Disk management, the key is visible but without volume and it says "no media" :
[no media in disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIGzM.jpg)
I can't right click to create a volume or other normal actions.
I can only right click in the Disk name (left column) and change the letter or display the properties. Changing the letter don't correct anything.

In "This PC", the usb key disk is not visible.

There is the diskpart informations (executed as administrator) :
[Diskpart infos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWqnX.jpg)

If I try to format or clean the E volume :
[Diskpart format volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDQO0.jpg)
Clean result in "There is no media in the device" error.
Format fails too.

I looked for solutions on the internet and tested the following software without success.

- AOMEI partition assistant - The key is not detected [aomei](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf55O.jpg)
- EaseUs Partition Master - The key is not detected in the Partition Manager [easeUs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Jxc.jpg) but I can select the usb key to create a bootable media (winPE) [bootable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZUN2.jpg) but it throw an error [error creating a bootable media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmM90.jpg).

Whan can I try to get my USB key back alive ?

I looked the similars questions (like [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem)) but no solution works.